# Screw backing failure in Bosch dishwasher

Tags: screws, dishwasher

Context: [Bosch SHE3ARF2UC/22](https://www.bosch-home.com/us/supportdetail/product/SHE3ARF2UC/22#/Tabs=section-spareparts/) provided [this link to diagrams](https://www.bosch-home.com/us/getAllImagesPDF?vibki=SHE3ARF2UC%2F22)

The plastic anchor, which holds the screw in place, seems to have broken:

[image]

The screw hole is in the dishwasher door:

[image]

Is there a simple remedy available that does not require either disassembling the the door to replace the broken plastic screw anchor?

Nameplate:

[image]

Update: per Isherwood's suggestion to disassemble, it seems that the two of Fascia Panel's screw holes are broken.

[image]

[image]

To replace the [Fascia Panel part #00686739](https://www.bosch-home.com/us/shop-productlist/00686739), it is $84 + shipping.  Before I do buy the panel.  I think it sensible to ask the community if there is a method (fender washer?) that will enable continuing using the current panel?

Is there a simple remedy available that does not require either disassembling the the door to replace the broken plastic screw anchor?

Would it be "good enough" to plug-up the hole or am I inviting disaster down the road?

Simple and effective (time saving) remedies are appreciated: thank you.

[image]

Comment: If there is no moving parts that the broken nut can jam up, I would dab a bit of silicon there.  It is high up so mainly just water splashes(not standing).  Seems to be just to hold the facing on.

Comment: @crip6759 Thanks for responding: are you suggesting plugging uptimes he hole with silicon and retiring the screw?

Comment: It does look like the screw is for holding the front facing on the door(not high in importance).  Keeping water out is the main thing.

Comment: Appears to be beyond the gasket, so it should not have much if any water exposure....

Comment: I'd consider creating a well or dam using tape all around the broken piece and then fill it with a plastic-compatible epoxy. Once it's set, drill a new hole a little smaller than the outside of the screw thread and a little bigger than the shaft of the screw. But considering that there are already other cracks visible in the plastic I don't know how long this would last...

Answer (score 1):

a longer screw and flat metal bar riveted (or bolted) behind the plastic, with a thread cut in it to accept the screw.